# Windows 10 Outlook 2010 reading pane will not remain after closing

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook-2010

Outlook 2010 suddenly began opening without the reading pane.  I can install the reading pane each time the program is open and works as it should but when I close and reopen the pane is gone.  The reading pane does not show in the add-ins area and it is not a disabled add-in.  It is not shown on the list.  I have repaired Office 2010 as this has in the past fixed other Outlook problems but it did not this time.  I figured it might be a Windows 10 issue but Windows just went through an update and still the same.  I'm out of ideas.  Anybody?

Answer (score 1):

The problem update is KB3114409 issued on 08 Dec.  If it is uninstalled, the problem goes away.  See also http://windowsitpro.com/patch-tuesday/december-s-first-recalled-patch-kb3114409

Answer (score 1):

There were a number of updates today (January 12 2016) from Microsoft. One of them fixed the problem of its disappearance that was introduced with the December 2015 update.
The Universe is back to normal (with Outlook)